How do I change the path of my installed Miniforge
So I installed miniforge3 to my root folder in Linux, now I'm getting some permissions error


Error Starting Kernel

[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/root/miniforge3/envs/xeus/bin//xcpp'

But instead of granting it access to my root directory, I was wondering if I could just move the installation directory instead and would everything still work if I did that.
Also these .conda .jupyter .ipython folders, should they be moved as well
Considered giving Jupyter access to my root folder.
